# Prove that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{|\alpha_n-a|}\leq\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{C}{|\alpha_n|}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let us consider the series of real numbers
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{|\alpha_n|}$$
and we assume it convergent. What can we say on
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{|\alpha_n-a|}$$
for each $a\in\mathbb R$ and $a\neq \alpha_n \forall n$? Surely the series is still convergents. But is it possible to conclude that there exists a constant $C$ such that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{|\alpha_n-a|}$$
is less than or equal of
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{C}{|\alpha_n|}$$
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reverse triangle inequality:

$$|\alpha_n - a| \geq | |\alpha_n| - |a| |$$

From some point on $|\alpha_n| \geq 2|a|$ so $|\alpha_n| - |a| \geq 1/2|\alpha_n|$ (because of convergence of the original series $\alpha_n \to \infty$). Let's say this happens for $n>N$.
So you can pick $C$ to be the maximum of the terms before $N$ and $2$.

Comment: First thing I try was the reverse triangle Inequality, I dropped it to soon. Nice Answer.

Comment: Good answer. Therefore $C=\max_{n\in[2,N]} \frac{2}{|\alpha_n|}$?

Comment: That is, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{|\alpha_n-a|}= \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{1}{|\alpha_n-a|}+\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{|\alpha_n-a|}\leq \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{1}{|\alpha_n-a|}+\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{2}{|\alpha_n|}$ How do I proceed?

Comment: Let $C_1 = \max{\frac{|\alpha_n|}{|\alpha_n - a|}}$, where the maximum is over $n \in \{1,2,\dots , N\}$. If $C_1 < 2$, pick $C=2$, otherwise $C=C_1$ is enough.

Comment: To clarify the term in the maximum: $\frac{1}{|\alpha_n - a|} \leq \frac{C_1}{|\alpha_n|}$ is equivalent to $\frac{|\alpha_n|}{|\alpha_n - a|} \leq C_1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum 1/|\alpha_n| < \infty \implies 1/|\alpha_n|\to 0 \implies |\alpha_n| \to \infty \implies (1/|\alpha_n|)/(1/|\alpha_n-a|)=|\,1-a/|\alpha_n \,| | \to 1.$$ By limit comparison, $\sum 1/|\alpha_n - a|<\infty.$